# ObservableObject is missing in Motherview

Tags: ios, xcode, view, swiftui, observableobject

I have the following viewfile:

```
import SwiftUI

class Progress: ObservableObject {
    @Published var index = 0
}

struct RegistrationView: View {
    @ObservedObject var progress: Progress
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $progress.index) {
            setUsernameView(progress: self.progress).tabItem{}.tag(0)
            setMasterPasswordView().tabItem{}.tag(1)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

when I am finished with my `setUserNameView()` I want to update index to 1 so that it switches to setMasterPasswordView. Im passing `progress` to the view and then inside to `another view` which updates the value.

Now xcode complains: `Missing argument for parameter 'progress' in call` the call is in the `contentView()`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RegistrationView()
    }
}
```

My question is, why does the view or any other view above `RegistrationView` need this object too and how do I save me from that work. I tried to make `progress` private but that doesn't work. I am defining the class and all other things in this view and I only need it for itself and the child of a child.

P.S. is there a better methode for observable objects? For example when I need the value in a main view and can change it in a child.child.child.view I have to pass it all the way down. And that seems kind of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to use it in parent view then just use locally as `StateObject`

```
struct RegistrationView: View {
    @StateObject var progress = Progress()    // << here !!

    // ... other code
```

Comment: okay my mistake was to use `@ObservedObject var progress: Progress` instead of `@ObservedObject var progress = Progress()`